# Access source container from recipient container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a mysql container created using docker file

```
from ubuntu:14.04

run apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

run apt-get install mysql-server -y

run apt-get install mysql-client -y

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y && \ oracle-java7-set-default

RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf

env set MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

EXPOSE 3306
```

and an java container from java:8 image. The java container is linked to mysql container using --link option.

```
docker run -it --link mysqlc:csql java:8
```

Now i need to execute mysql commands from java container but mysql commands not working in java container. What is the problem?

I need to start mysql, create databases from java container? How to do this?
Do i need to use another image other than java to access mysql container?

Comment: You should group your RUN commands in order to avoid many layers, have better consistency with `apt-get update` and so, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ and I do not see any `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile, so I am surprised

Answer (score 0):

An approach is building your own Java image that contains mysql-client as long as Java:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM Java:8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install mysql-client
```

Build:

```
docker build . -t my-java-mysql
```

Run:

```
docker run -it --link mysqlc:csql my-java-mysql:8
```

Then you have `mysql` client command available in your Java container.